# Rails Devise Recoverable - Not receiving forgot your password e-mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.1'

gem 'rails',                   '5.0.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'devise',                  '~> 4.2'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.11'
gem 'faker',                   '1.6.3'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.3.6'
gem 'puma'
gem 'uglifier',                '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.1'          
gem 'turbolinks',              '5.0.0.beta2'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.4.1'
gem 'gon',                     '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
gem 'filepicker-rails',        '~> 2.1'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'  
gem 'haml'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'omniauth-stripe-connect'
gem 'appsignal'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

production.rb

```
 # Devise config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'd*****.com' }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }
```

devise.rb

```
config.mailer_sender = 'dwo*******@gmail.com'
```

application.yml

```
production:
  STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: "sk_live_6yjOP****************"
  STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY: "pk_live_85nZsm****************"
  STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID: "ca_95VFITa4PgcUn****************"
  CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID: "acct_18kh****************"
  GMAIL_DOMAIN: "gmail.com"
  GMAIL_USERNAME: "d********@gmail.com"
  GMAIL_PASSWORD: "****************"
```

heroku logs

```
2016-12-03T23:57:40.189178+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-03T23:57:40.189101 #4]  INFO -- : [1b1fec5e-5916-4f73-8d8e-829d08fbad0b]   Rendering devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb
2016-12-03T23:57:40.190121+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-03T23:57:40.190063 #4]  INFO -- : [1b1fec5e-5916-4f73-8d8e-829d08fbad0b]   Rendered devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb (0.8ms)
2016-12-03T23:57:40.314034+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2016-12-03T23:57:40.313920 #4] DEBUG -- : [1b1fec5e-5916-4f73-8d8e-829d08fbad0b] Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 130.1ms
2016-12-03T23:57:40.486943+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-03T23:57:40.486840 #4]  INFO -- : [1b1fec5e-5916-4f73-8d8e-829d08fbad0b] Sent mail to d**************@gmail.com (172.7ms)
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487001+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2016-12-03T23:57:40.486935 #4] DEBUG -- : [1b1fec5e-5916-4f73-8d8e-829d08fbad0b] Date: Sat, 03 Dec 2016 23:57:40 +0000
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487003+00:00 app[web.1]: From: d**************@gmail.com
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487003+00:00 app[web.1]: Reply-To: d**************@gmail.com
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487004+00:00 app[web.1]: To: dwo**********@gmail.com
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487005+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <58435bf44d8ed_43fcedcb1be2c98860@bddbaa93-132b-48e8-9748-833df42451fc.mail>
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487006+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: Reset password instructions
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487007+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487008+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487008+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487010+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>Hello d**************@gmail.com!</p>
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487009+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487009+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487012+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487012+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487011+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487013+00:00 app[web.1]: <p><a href="https://d**************.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=8Ash**************">Change my password</a></p>
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487014+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487013+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487015+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
2016-12-03T23:57:40.487016+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-03T23:57:40.490471+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-03T23:57:40.490413 #4]  INFO -- : [1b1fec5e-5916-4f73-8d8e-829d08fbad0b] Redirected to https://www.**************.com/users/sign_in
2016-12-03T23:57:40.490700+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-03T23:57:40.490635 #4]  INFO -- : [1b1fec5e-5916-4f73-8d8e-829d08fbad0b] Completed 302 Found in 537ms (ActiveRecord: 7.8ms)
```

I registered my env variables on heroku and double checked they were correct in the dashboard.

No clue why I am not receiving the e-mails. Heroku logs isn't pointing me anywhere to why its not working. Anyone have any ideas whats wrong with my code? Thank you!!!

Comment: Not a very direct solution to your problem, but you don't actually need to attach the confirmation emails to your gmail. Since you are using heroku, simply set up SENDGRID and it should work like a charm.

Comment: @angkiki Thanks for the direction. I am working on implementing SendGrid with my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encounter a similar problem. The mails were sent but were marked as spam because the domain is not verified. Look in your spam folder to see if the mails are there.

Also in development i recommend using 'letter-opener' gem to view the emails.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Still not appearing in my spam though.